# Making a one-dimensional plot with names of the data points in R

Tags: r, plot, scale

I have a list of data points (0.2, 0.8, 0.95) that I want to plot on a line. I want to create a one-dimensional scale (vertical or horizontal) of this range of values with the names of those data points (apples, bananas, tomatoes) juxtaposed to the data points, which are positioned on the scale. I know there is a relatively easy function to this in a package but I can't find it anymore! Please help :).

Thank you,
Annemarie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a handy function in the vegan library to do this:

```
x <- c(1,3.4,7,8,9,15,19)
names <- c("apple","pear","banana","grapefruit","orange","tomato","cucumber")
library(vegan)
linestack(x, names, side = "left")
```

Hopefully it is of use to somebody some time.

Comment: It seems like your code is missing the actual function. Unless I am missing something, the code you post simply creates 2 objects that are lists and then loads `vegan`.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing t come to my mind was to do it by hand:

```
plot(rep(1,3),c(0.2, 0.8, 0.95),ylim=c(0,1),axes=F,xlab="",ylab="",type="o",pch=19)
axis(side=2)
text(rep(1,3),c(0.2, 0.8, 0.95),c("apples", "bananas", "tomatoes"),pos=4,xpd=T)
```

[image]

because then you have full control. There is also a function called `stripchart()`, that does 1-d plotting:

```
stripchart(c(0.2, 0.8, 0.95),vertical=T)
text(rep(1,3),c(0.2, 0.8, 0.95),c("apples", "bananas", "tomatoes"),pos=4)
```

[image]
neither is very beautiful, but you can take it from there.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about a function to do this, closest I can think of if `dotchart` but its not the same. However, how about this:

```
dat <- c(0.2,0.8,0.95)
names(dat) <- c("apples","bananas","tomatoes")
plot(c(1,1),range(dat),type="l",col="lightgrey",xlab="",xaxt="n")
points(rep(1,length(dat)),dat)
text(1,dat,names(dat),pos=4)
```

Which results in:

[image]